# SwiftUI x Firebase - Trouble Waiting for Firebase Results before Executing Code

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Thanks in advance! I'm currently trying to learn how to build mobile apps with SwiftUI, and wanted to use Firebase for cloud based services (database, auth). I'm running into some trouble trying to implement a closure to ensure that proceeding code only executes after performing Firebase tasks. I've tried to write a closure and @escaping function within my findUser() function, but my general program is still not waiting for findUser() to complete before proceeding.

Any thoughts here? I've pasted my findUser() function below, as well as how I'm currently calling it

```
func findUser(searchKey: String, searchValue: Any, completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: Dictionary<String, Any>?) -> Void) {

    var user: Dictionary<String, Any>? = nil
    let db: Firestore = getFirebaseConn()
    let usersRef = db.collection(fire.userPath) // db ref

    usersRef.whereField(searchKey, isEqualTo: searchValue).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("There was an error with retrieving the query snapshot")
            completionHandler(user)
            return
        }

        if let err = err {
            print("There was an error finding the user: \(err)")
            completionHandler(user)
            return
        }

        let docsList = querySnapshot.documents
        if docsList.count == 1 { // expected case we want
            print("Found by \(searchKey)!") // temp
            user = docsList[0].data()
        } else if docsList.count == 0 {
            print("Not found by \(searchKey)!") // temp
        } else { // error case...
            print("Ok, we should NOT be getting more than 1 result from \(searchKey), kekw!")
        }
        completionHandler(user)
        return
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
var userFound: Dictionary<String, Any>?             
findUser(searchKey: "email", searchValue: search) { (result) in
    print("Ok we got our first result")
    print(result)
    if result != nil {
        userFound = result!
    } 

}

// this chunk of code is being called BEFORE the results closure
if userFound == nil {
    print("Not found!")
} else {
    print("Found!")
}
```

Additional Notes:

I want to achieve something like,

1. Click search
2. Firebase finds user
3. Declares user found
4. returns user

Currently, it is:

1. Click Search
2. declares user not found
3. returns nothing
4. Firebase finds user

#### Edits for correct solution!

findUser() did not need changes, but the structure of my code did. In the callback section, this change was needed:

```
var userFound: Dictionary<String, Any>?             
findUser(searchKey: "email", searchValue: search) { (result) in
    print("Ok we got our first result")
    print(result)
    if result != nil {
        userFound = result!
    } 
   // this chunk of code is being called BEFORE the results closure
   if userFound == nil {
       print("Not found!")
   } else {
       print("Found!")
   }
}
// There should NOT be code after this to mimic a synchronous step of retrieving user --> loading!
```

Comment: When you say the `"my code below this function call is NOT waiting for this closure to be completed"`, can I just clarify, does that mean inside the `findUser` callback (before the `}`) or outside (after the `}`)?

Comment: My program will first declare that a user is "Not found!" and then find a user and print that user. Does this make sense @George_E

Comment: The edit helped. This is the exact solution my answer fixes, hope it all works now!

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: Is this code `if userFound == nil` actually directly following `findUser(searchKey`? If so, that's the issue and you've circumvented handling your data asynchronously. Code is faster than the internet and it will take time for the code inside *findUser* to run e.g. it's dependent on Firebase returning results from the server. Just move that code inside the `findUser` closure and you're set.

Comment: I expected the `result` object being passed within the closure of findUser() to update my `var userFound` BEFORE the second check occurs. But right now, given this code, what I'm getting is `print("Not found!")` running first, then Firebase printing out a user being found. Therefore, not synchronous as I hoped it would be. @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is the question is pretty close and you're kinda dealing with the asynchronous nature of Firebase correctly except one thing: code following a (Firebase) closure will execute before the code within the closure.

It takes time for Firebase to return results and code is faster than the internet. So you need to deal with Firebase data within it's closure (or within the completion handler in this case)

The fix is to handle data when it's available like this

```
findUser(searchKey: "email", searchValue: search) { (result) in
    if result != nil {
        print("user was found")
        //go do something with the user
    } else {
        print("no user was found!")
    }
}
//any code here will execute before the code in the above closure
```

Comment: To clarify: does this mean for my button function, all code post a Firebase closure must be handled within the closure itself, else it will behave in an async manner?

Comment: @LeoLien Yes, I think. Let me re-state my answer; firebase closures are asynchronous; data returned from Firebase is only valid within that closure. If you look at my answer, findUser calls a Firebase function; that function gets some data from Firebase and when that data is returned from the internet within the closure it's passed to the completion handler and back to findUser as the result. So right after the closing } I have //any code here will... meaning if you replace that with `print("Hello, World")` then Hello, World will print before either user was found or no user was found

Answer (score 1):

When `completionHandler` is called, this is known as a callback. As soon as you call `completionHandler(["hello": "world"])` for example, it will run the code where you have `print("Ok we got our first result")`.

Although this code inside the callback only gets called after the work is done, everything outside continues to run without delay. This is similar to when using `DispatchQueue`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    print("Delays by 1 second")
}

print("Instant")
```

The solution is to run all the code that must wait inside of the callback, below:

```
if result != nil {
    userFound = result!
}

if userFound == nil {
    print("Not found!")
} else {
    print("Found!")
}
```

Tip: rather than the above code, for neater code and reduced risk of bugs/crashes due to the force unwrap, you could do:

```
guard let result = result else { return }
print("Result:", result)

let userFound = result["user"] // I don't know what this variable is, but I can assume it comes from the result

if userFound == nil {
    print("Not found!")
} else {
    print("Found!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm not sure I understand how to run code that must wait inside a callback syntactically. Is there any chance you could show me an example?

Comment: @LeoLien Updated my answer to hopefully reflect where the code should go.