# Firebase, Swift, Cannot link data to tableview regardless of getting the class data in func loadData()

Tags: swift, firebase

// ViewController code:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var students = [Student]()
    var db: Firestore!
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func loadData() {
        
        let studentCollection = db.collection("students")
        studentCollection.getDocuments() { (result, err) in
            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            }
            else
            {
                for document in result!.documents
                {
                    let conversionResult = Result
                    {
                        try document.data(as: Student.self)
                    }
                    switch conversionResult
                    {
                        case .success(let convertedDoc):
                            if var student = convertedDoc
                            {
                                student.id = document.documentID
                                print("Student: \(student)")
                                
                                self.students.append(student)

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("Document does not exist")
                            }
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Error decoding movie: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return students.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let student = students[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell

        cell.setRecord(student: student)
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

// output of student data:

```
Student: Student(id: Optional("BDMLFV6Z6pKoiEWwmdTq"), name: "Reina", studentId: 500104, ifAttends: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false], marks: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
Student: Student(id: Optional("TnimfWwBSLm8erL5Xs7u"), name: "Guy", studentId: 500103, ifAttends: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false], marks: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
Student: Student(id: Optional("WrikwEsjipuIbOO5iE7d"), name: "Kate", studentId: 500102, ifAttends: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false], marks: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
Student: Student(id: Optional("cPIMkDBGd0Q0m4MPmaii"), name: "Emily", studentId: 500105, ifAttends: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false], marks: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
Student: Student(id: Optional("zuSUiVz4CiXjBkHciQGK"), name: "Veronica", studentId: 500101, ifAttends: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false], marks: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
```

Comment: Call `tableView.reloadData()` in callback block, after appending data

Comment: Fetching data from a database runs on a different queue, so as not to block the UI thread when you are fetching it. Therefore, completion closure for `studentCollection.getDocuments()` runs asynchronously, so by the time you call `self.tableView.reloadData()` the data is not ready yet. What you need to do is call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in completion closure, and also read up on asynchronous execution.

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous so data from Firebase is valid within the closure following the firebase call. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541749/swiftui-x-firebase-trouble-waiting-for-firebase-results-before-executing-code/65551233#65551233) for more info.